# Why is my wireless very unstable, even after trying Wicd?

Tags: wireless, networking

[Here is my script output.](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/9207614/)

I'm a brand new Linux user. I installed it on an old Windows 8.1 machine. Wireless Internet will be connected for a minute or two, then I will not be able to load Web pages. I tried installing Wicd Network Manager, but it didn't remedy the problem.

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an updated driver, with an internet connection do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Run the command **iwconfig**

Find what your wireless connection name is and run
**sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off**

Example:

```
ee@sys6:~$ iwconfig

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"5ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: E0:3F:49:93:3F:14   
          Bit Rate=390 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:74   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0f2  no wireless extensions.


ee@sys6:~$ sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off

ee@sys6:~$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"5ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: E0:3F:49:93:3F:14   
          Bit Rate=390 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:74   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0f2  no wireless extensions.
```